# Need to copy function's arguments from HTML source

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I need to find string with partial match (function name and unknown arguments), extract arguments and manually launch script with userscript. Problem is, most of other scripts are hazardous, so I blocked them all, which makes that function nothing more than string of text in the middle of page, and outside of DOM elements on top of that.
So.. yeah. I'm out of ideas. In short, I need:

1. Find string that calls up function and appoint it with arguments to variable;
2. Extract from that variable arguments

Any help?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We can't begin to help you without examples of the kinds of texts you need to analyze and the outputs you expect from them. And generally, the community expects to see what attempts you've made or what avenues of solving the problem you've pursued.

Comment: *"and outside of DOM elements on top of that"* It'll be in *some* DOM element, at least `html`, `head`, or `body`. (And if it's in `head` as text, that would be an invalid document.)

Comment: Yeah, It's in `body`, I suppose. The thing is, it's not wrapped in any other DOM element, so no help pinpointing it.   ....wait, does `<script></script>` block actually counts as DOM element?

Comment: Yes, `script` tags create `script` elements. If they have inline code, that's accessible as their text content.

Comment: Okay, I can do that, with jQuery selectors. Only second part left, I think I need RegEx here, but it's something I'm especially bad with.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

- rewrite function ;
- use `console.trace()` ;
- or show code source of function like this : `functionName.toString()`.

```js
const ouput = document.getElementById("output");

function littleBrother(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
   console.log("I'm good.", arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

(function overWriteFunction(original) {
  ouput.value = original.toString();
  
  littleBrother = function () {
    console.log("My little brother will say something, with this args :", arguments);
    console.trace(); // Watch your console.
    original.apply(window, arguments);
  };
})(littleBrother);


littleBrother(12, 5, 6);
```

```html
<textarea id="output" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```